# Unable to merge a Transaction set with SetOptions

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have to use a Transaction for setting and updating certain data in Firestore. I would like to merge new data if old data already exists. This is possible without transactions, but with them I can't seem to do it, even though it says you can.

From the Flutter Firestore implementation I can see the following doc:

```
/// Writes to the document referred to by the provided [DocumentReference].
/// If the document does not exist yet, it will be created. If you pass
/// SetOptions, the provided data can be merged into the existing document.
  Future<void> set(
  ///.....
```

I have Googled about the `SetOptions` class and it does exist in theory (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SetOptions) but I can't seem to find any Flutter example of it, and it doesn't seem to exist in the Flutter version of the lib, nor is it a parameter for this method.

This is my current transaction call:

```
  transaction.set(doc.reference, {
    "liked": FieldValue.arrayUnion([entryInfo.id]),
  });
```

Is it possible to do this in the Flutter version of Firestore or is it a mistake and it's not implemented yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [API documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Transaction-class.html), it doesn't seem there is a variant of transaction.set() that accepts something similar to `SetOptions`.  You might want to [send feedback](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues) about this.

Comment: I've posted an issue but it doesn't seem like the team has picked it up or noticed it. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36950#issuecomment-515749032